# WP-Super-Cache activation errors

Tags: wordpress, caching, plugins

I have to set up the cache on a WordPress project, which is already on "support mode" in the agency for a while.

The plugin WP Super Cache was already installed so I activated it, to setting up it.

I work locally on dev mode and the project have a preprod and a prod environments.

When I activated it, the following error messages appear in back-office :

> Warning:
>   include(/var/www/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-base.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php on line 65
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   ‘/var/www/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-base.php’
>   for inclusion (include_path=’.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear’) in
>   /var/www/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php on line 65
>
> Warning:
>   include_once(/var/www/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/ossdl-cdn.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php on line 82
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   ‘/var/www/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/ossdl-cdn.php’
>   for inclusion (include_path=’.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear’) in
>   /var/www/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php on line 82

Looking in the file wp-cache.php on lines 65 and 82, it says that :

```
include(WPCACHEHOME . 'wp-cache-base.php');
```

> Path ‘dirname(**FILE**).’/…wp-cache-base.php’ not found Include
>   expression is not resolved

```
include_once( WPCACHEHOME . 'ossdl-cdn.php' );
```

> Path ‘dirname(**FILE**).’/…ossdl-cdn.php’ not found Include expression
>   is not resolved

So I was thinking about changing the path. However, this is bothering me because I am afraid that this action will be potentially a troubleshooting cause when the plugin will have to be updated.

I have no ideas how I can fix it. 
Uninstall and reinstall the plugin ?
Use an other plugin to manage the cache?

Thank you in advance for your answers. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 11):

WP Super Cache puts the below line in your **wp-config.php** file.  Remove the line from your **wp-config.php** file and reinstall and reactivate the plugin.

```
define( ‘WPCACHEHOME’, ‘/home/USERNAME/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/’ ); //Added by WP-Cache Manager
```

I encountered the same problem after moving my Wordpress directory to the root of my site. If you get the problem and can't deactivate the erroring plugin, go to your /wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache and remove or rename the directory. This will manually deactivate this so you can install a fresh instance.